# Django customize AdminModel view

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my Django application I have `Guest` user accounts that are created for all unregistered users (they all have email='guest@mysite.com'). At the same time I create some **demo objects** related to the Guest account. 
These objects live in the same table (have the same model) as objects for registered users. And I have more that one type (model) of these objects like:

```
class Object1(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(...)
    ...

class Object2(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(...)
    ...
```

And what I would like to achieve is to **filter out** all objects related to guest accounts when I view them in **django admin**.

Right now I subclass `django.contrib.admin.views.main.ChangeList` and override `get_query_set` method to do the required exclude, and I redefine `get_changelist` method of django's ModelAdmin class at runtime:

```
class FilteredChangeList(ChangeList):
    def get_query_set(self):
        qs = super(FilteredChangeList, self).get_query_set()
        if is_related_to(self.model, Profile):
            qs = qs.exclude(user__email='guest@mysite.com')
        return qs

def my_getchangelist(self, request, **kwargs):
    return FilteredChangeList

ModelAdmin.get_changelist = my_getchangelist
```

I suppose redefining django's methods at runtime is a bad practice, so is there any correct solution for the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guess you are doing a lot more work than necessary. You could also create your own `ModelAdmin` class and overwrite its `queryset` method, no need to construct your own `ChangeList` class:

```
class MyFilteredAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyFilteredAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if is_related_to(self.model, Profile):
            qs = qs.exclude(user__email='guest@mysite.com')
        return qs
```

You could then either register your models directly with this new admin class - `admin.site.register(Model, MyFilteredAdmin)` - or create subclasses that inherit from `MyFilteredAdmin` instead from django's `ModelAdmin`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also have proxy models. You could have one that has 'real' users, and one that has 'guest' users.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `ModelAdmin` and override the `get_changelist` method instead of redefining at runtime.

```
class FilteredModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return FilteredChangeList
```

Then register your models with FilteredModelAdmin instead of `ModelAdmin`.

```
admin.site.register(Object1, FilteredModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Object2, FilteredModelAdmin)
```

If you need to customize any other settings for your models subclass `FilteredModelAdmin` instead of `ModelAdmin`.

```
class Object1ModelAdmin(FilteredModelAdmin)
    # other customizations here

admin.site.register(Object1, Object1ModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Yes, but then I should write custom ModelAdmin for every type of related object I have.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you don't need to customize any other admin settings for the model, register it with `FilteredModelAdmin` instead of `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: I think lazerscience's answer is better -- I don't think you need to subclass `ChangeList`, just override `ModelAdmin.queryset`.